# How do I make it my primary OS 16.04 LTS Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, lts

So I downloaded Ubuntu as a dual boot but I now change my mind and would like  to delete the dual boot and install it as my primary OS how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can get a backup of your Ubuntu, put your live USB and choose install Ubuntu with delete entire disk option to have only Ubuntu on your machine.

Comment: @Egrimo: That's kind of a hassle since one can just remove the other operating system and keep the current installation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two options.It's basically Ubuntu-App way or GParted way.

### 1)Ubuntu-App way

Connect your live USB to the machine and choose "try Ubuntu without installing". After it booted up to the screen, open commandline and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

[image]

After that, OS-Uninstaller will open and asks you which OS do you want to remove. You choose Windows and it will delete the OS and keep your Ubuntu.

### 2)GParted way

This way is little bit longer than the other way. You boot your machine with live USB and open the app "**GParted**". Here, you can see your partitions. Windows partitions are usually formatted as NFTS, so you can see them easily. Choose NFTS partitions and delete them.
[image]

After deleting there will be exist a "**Unallocated**" partition. Choose your Ubuntu partition, right click and select "Resize" option. Here you can add these unallocated space to Ubuntu.

Last, perform actions that you did in the GParted app. Reboot the machine and Windows will be gone for good. If you see Windows option in the GRUB menu, you can write `sudo update-grub` to update your GRUB options.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed **Ubuntu** and you have a lot of things on it, so you don't want to reboot your whole computer, you can use **Gparted** to delete the other partitions and resize the memory. I actually had the same problem and use this tutorial : https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/ you can follow step by step what to do and remember to safe your files before doing this.

Comment: That's step one. You also need to remove the Windows boot entry.

Comment: that's what the link is for so the people who read my answer would follow a better step by step than my answer.